# How to code-reuse a Jenkins shared library?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a [Jenkins shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), and have files that contain functions and classes defined like this

```
src/com/company/someDir/SomeFile.groovy
----------------------------------------
package com.company.someDir
class SomeClass {
  ...
}
```

How can I declare a variable of type `SomeClass` in the `SomeOtherClass` definition? I tried these...

```
src/com/company/someDir/SomeOtherFile.groovy
--------------------------------------------
package com.company.someDir
import com.company.someDir.SomeFile
class SomeOtherClass {
  SomeClass aClass=null // ...or...
  com.company.someDir.SomeFile.SomeClass aClass=null
  ...
}
```

...but I get "Unable to resolve class" compilation error in both cases in my Jenkins pipeline job. What's the correct way?

EDIT: Per comments below

NOTE: I have a Jenkins pipeline job, and the inline pipeline code is simply

```
node("build-node") {
  // Shared library set up in Jenkins system config
  @Library("shared-library")
  def object = new com.company.someDir.SomeOtherFile() 
  object.somePublicFunc()
}
```

When I run the job I get the error.

Comment: Did you setup it as Global Shared Libraries in Jenkins? Also, did you use the @Library annotation? I don't see it on your code

Comment: Yes, I have ALL that working. Otherwise, I wouldn't have gotten as far as getting the compilation error in my Jenkins pipeline job. It's just the above code itself that's problematic.

Comment: in code above you also must use @Library, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within shared library and within same package you don't need to import anything. Inside one package it's transparent. Please remove all imports from packages.

e.g.

```
src/com/company/someDir/SomeOtherFile.groovy
--------------------------------------------
package com.company.someDir

class SomeOtherClass {
  SomeClass aClass=null // ...or...
  com.company.someDir.SomeFile.SomeClass aClass=null
  ...
}
```

Inside pipeline you have import classes.

e.g.

```
// this must be first before import
@Library("shared-library") _    

// after that pipeline knows about SomeOtherFile class
import com.company.someDir.SomeOtherFile

node("build-node") {
  
  def object = new SomeOtherFile() 
  object.somePublicFunc()
}
```

Good luck

Comment: I did exactly this, and got the same error. Thanks.

Comment: could you please double check shared library configuration. Name should be same.

Comment: Max, this worked. I was too blind and didn't see the "_" (underscore) at the end of the `@Library()` line. Thanks you!